# Transitioning a cloud service from being local to being hosted on Windows Azure

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services, windows-phone-7, azure

I'm trying to host a very simple database on Azure and going out of my mind doing so. I've managed to get a local service running and communicating with my WP7 app just fine :).

I got this far by following this tutorial:
http://breathingtech.com/2011/how-to-use-wcf-services-to-access-sql-azure-database-from-windows-phone-7-app-part-1/

The tutorial provides steps to publish the service to Azure but my version of Visual Studio (2010 Professional SP1) is different and I can't do the final bit (hosting it on Azure).

When I hit 'publish...' as per the tutorial I get this (what do I do next?):
[image]

Can anybody point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you want to follow that tutorial, you should right click the project, but instead of choosing **Publish** you should choose **Package**. After packaging this will open up a new Explorer window with the 2 files (the package and the cscfg).

Then you can simply go ahead and follow the rest of the tutorial.

Alternatively, you could simply change the environment from **Staging** to **Production** in the screen which you display in your question and click publish. This packages the application and deploys it to the selected hosted service (in your case **apprehensive3months**). If you do this, you won't need to upload the files manually in the portal (as described in the tutorial).